# How do I fix this problem. I'm trying to use the len function but it's not working as desired

Tags: python, list

```py
def mult(numbers):
        return [10] * len(numbers)

number = [1,2,5,6,7,8,10]
mult(number)
```

I expect the output of `[10,20,50.......]`
but this is the output I'm getting `[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]`

Comment: This is not what `len()` does (obviously). If not done already you should work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you're doing, annotated:

```
def mult(numbers):
    return [10] * len(numbers)
    # [10]                -->  Take the list [10]
    # len(numbers)        -->  Take the length of the list `numbers`, which has 7 elements
    # [10] * len(numbers) -->  repeat [10] seven times, to get [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

I think the problem is you're misunderstanding what the `len()` function does, and how the `*` (multiplication) operator works with lists. If you want to multiply *each number* by 10, you would do something like this:

```
def mult(numbers):
    multed = []                 # create an empty list to store the result
    for num in numbers:         # iterate through the elements in `numbers` one by one
        multed.append(10 * num) # add (10 * element) to our new list
    return multed               # return the list we've created
```

Python also has *list comprehensions* that make this code more concise:

```
def mult(numbers):
    return [10*num for num in numbers]
    # this does the same thing as above
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
def mult(numbers):
    return [10*i for i in numbers]
number = [1,2,5,6,7,8,10]
mult(number)
```

Your approach is simply taking the value `10` and copying a number of times equal to the `len` of your input array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this way.

```
def mult(number):
     return 10 * number

number = [1,2,5,6,7,8,10]
answer = []

for i in number:
    answer.append(mult(i))

print(answer)
```